# Sheets Run script on edit of a range of cells (False to True)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that needs to run when a sheet is edited. I need it to run anytime a box in column L (L2:L260) is checked. I originally wrote the script to run on a button push (check a number of boxes, click the button and it would run), but it can't be run by other people who need to be able to use it. The script originally worked great when it was click the button, but once I added in the onEdit stuff...it completely stopped working. Here's what I have:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //Get the sheet you want to work with. 
  var editrange = {
    top : 2,
    bottom : 260,
    left : 11,
    right : 11};
  var thisrow = e.range.getrow();
  if (thisrow < editrange.top || thisrow > editrange.bottom)
    return;
  var thiscolumn = e.range.getcolumn();
  if (thiscolumn < editrange.left || thiscolumn > editrange.right)
    return;
  var ss = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Responsible");
  //Grab the entire Range, and grab whatever values you need from it. EX: rangevalues
  var range8 = sheet.getRange("K3:K90");
  var range28 = sheet.getRange("M3:M90");
  var range2values8 = range28.getValues();
  var rangevalues8 = range8.getValues();
  //Loops through range results
  for (var i in rangevalues8) {
    // for (var j in rangevalues) {
    Logger.log("rangevalues8["+i+"]["+0+"] is:"+rangevalues8[i][0]);//Added

    //Set the rules logic
    if (rangevalues8[i][0] == true) { //Modified
      //Set the cell 
      range2values8[i][0] += 1; //Directly add 1 to range2values
      Logger.log(range2values8);//Added
    }
  }

  //copy new information
  var destination = ss.getSheetByName('Compiled Data');//whatever page
  var destCell8 = destination.getRange("I183:I270");
  destCell8.setValues(range2values8);

  //clear checkboxes
  var cleaning = ss.getSheetByName('Asset Bank');
  var cleaningcell8 = cleaning.getRange("A3:A90").getValues();
  range8.setValues(cleaningcell8);
}
```

Thanks for any help I can get!

Comment: `getcloumn()` on line 10 it should be `getcolumn()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately, it still isn't running, even with fixing the spelling mistake.

Comment: can you share a test spreadsheet I'll be happy to chat and help you with that

Comment: Here is a link to a sheet setup the exact same way (minus all of the things that aren't necessary for this):  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PWaWm7AryljOMd5Aq1O2RSADyRFNVZbUDqKO__SzW2w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Note that simple triggers do not let exceptions raise to the UI. Check Stackdriver Logs and you will probably see an error regarding the lack of a method `getSheetByName` for an object of class `Sheet`. Your code assigns `ss` as `e.range.getSheet()` when you probably meant `e.source` to access the`Spreadsheet` in which the edit was made.

Comment: I'm on the spreadsheet

Comment: Thanks! It's frustrating having 95% of it but missing that last piece. Sorry I missed you on chat. I had it left open on my screen while I had classes the rest of the day. I really appreciate the help.

Followup question: if I wanted to run multiple of these in the same sheet (like one for column A), is that something that can be done by copying the script and doing something to the name of the function?

Comment: did my answer solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, problem solved. Thanks! It appears to work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After review of your code I guess the `getcloumn()` you've edited in an also erroneous method `getcolumn()`, the

```
var ss = e.range.getSheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Responsible");
```

and the

`e.range.getrow()`

seems to be the major problems

correct syntax is:

```
getColumn();
getRow();
```

and you need to use the function `getSheetByName(name)` out from a `spreadsheet` object not a `sheet` object.

Here is the corrected code:

```
 function onEdit(e) {

    //Get the sheet you want to work with. 
    var editrange = {
        top: 2,
        bottom: 260,
        left: 11,
        right: 11
    };
    //getRow() and not getrow()
    var thisrow = e.range.getRow();
    if (thisrow < editrange.top || thisrow > editrange.bottom) return;
    //getColumn() and not getcolumn()
    var thiscolumn = e.range.getColumn();
    if (thiscolumn < editrange.left || thiscolumn > editrange.right) return;
    //Line that replaces the erroneous 'var ss = e.range.getSheet()';
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Responsible");
    //Grab the entire Range, and grab whatever values you need from it. EX: rangevalues
    var range8 = sheet.getRange("K3:K90");
    var range28 = sheet.getRange("M3:M90");
    var range2values8 = range28.getValues();
    var rangevalues8 = range8.getValues();
    //Loops through range results
    for (var i in rangevalues8) {
        Logger.log("rangevalues8[" + i + "][" + 0 + "] is:" + rangevalues8[i][0]); //Added
        //Set the rules logic
        if (rangevalues8[i][0] == true) { //Modified
            //Set the cell 
            range2values8[i][0] += 1; //Directly add 1 to range2values
            Logger.log(range2values8); //Added
        }
    }
    //copy new information
    var destination = ss.getSheetByName('Compiled Data'); //whatever page
    var destCell8 = destination.getRange("I183:I270");
    destCell8.setValues(range2values8);
    //clear checkboxes
    var cleaning = ss.getSheetByName('Asset Bank');
    var cleaningcell8 = cleaning.getRange("A3:A90").getValues();
    range8.setValues(cleaningcell8);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly.

If I wanted to run this script and a duplicate of this script that reads column 6 instead of 11 and also copies data from column 8 (H) and pastes it into a different range on the 'Compiled Data' tab (I93:I180), how would I name the two functions so they don't both run?

Comment: that's very easy but's that a different question. Basically you create a function with arguments you can pass into the function and call them conditionnnaly in onEdit.